# What do we need to learn before starting learning netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I wanted to do some software development using java !!! I know C++ fairly well !! So I needed help asking where should I start from !!! Learning java from scratch I keep hearing of but what type of java ?? I mean one used in the competitive programming or which one 
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to familiarize yourself with the [Stack Overflow help file](http://stackoverflow.com/help), which will help you understand what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site. This site is intended to help you obtain answers to *specific programming questions*, as opposed to providing tutorial, design or code review assistance. That said... did you try searching for [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=netbeans+tutorial+for+beginners+java) yourself?

Comment: There's plenty of youtube tutorials and netbeans have it themselves on how to use it!

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans is just an IDE ( integrated development environment )  for Java.

Java is a programming language so your question quite doesn't make sense (that's why you're getting downvoted )

So, I would suggest you to start learning Java from scratch and then as you use it you'll learn to use Netbeans or your editor of choice.

You can start with the [Java tutorial](http://tps://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)